# How can passing a deviant number of function parameters in C still end up working as intended?

Tags: c, function, parameters, parameter-passing

Let's take [**this**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2265/16955) codegolf example, which reverses the `stdin` character buffer, and prints it on `stdout`:

```
main(_){write(read(0,&_,1)&&main());}
```

Here `write()` prints the intended output even though it seems to make do with only 1 parameter passed to it. For comparison, here's the actual `write()` prototype which clearly specifies 3 parameters:

```
ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

<s>Moreover, in the example above, the only parameter passed to `write()` is (as far as I can tell) not even the 1st one, but the 2nd, which corresponds to the buffer pointer.</s>  So how are the file descriptor and size values set correctly here? **UPDATE**: the only argument *explicitly* passed is argument 1. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636491/765294) for more information.

Can anyone give a precise explanation for this hack?

Comment: On my system, `write` is declared in `unistd.h`, what header files were included in this program?

Comment: @OregonTrail None. That line is the _entire_ C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured this out now. As OregonTrail crucially discovered, the code example in question only works on 32-bit systems. This lead to me suspect the code relies on the commonly used 32-bit calling conventioned called CDECL. To quote this [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions):

> In the CDECL calling convention the following holds:
>
> - **Arguments are passed on the stack** in Right-to-Left order, and return values are passed in eax.
> - The calling function cleans the stack. This allows CDECL functions to have variable-length argument lists (aka variadic functions). For this reason **the number of arguments is not appended to the name of the function by the compiler, and the assembler and the linker are therefore unable to determine if an incorrect number of arguments is used.**

In chronological order:

- `1` is pushed to the stack as the 3rd parameter (length) to `read()`.
- the pointer `&_` to a char buffer is pushed to the stack as the 2nd parameter to `read()`.
- `0` is pushed to the stack as the 1st parameter (the file descriptor of `stdin`) to `read()`.
- `read()` is called, returns, and now `write()` is about to be called.
- The assembly was generated based on the premise given in the source code that `write()` takes only 1 paramater, so only one item is "cleaned"/popped off the stack.
- `1` is pushed to the stack as the 1st parameter (the file descriptor of `stdout`) to `write()`, because 1 is the result of the `write(read(0,&_,1)&&main()` expression.
- `write()` needs 3 parameters so reads the top 3 items on the stack.

So why does `write()` write correctly? Because the 2nd and 3d item on the stack have not been touched since they were put there for `read()` to read, and the 2nd and 3rd parameters of `read()` and `write()` in this case need to hold the exact same values anyway: a pointer to the char buffer and a length of 1.

Comment: Some things yet to be explained. The expression `read(0,&_,1) && main()` writes a value to `eax`, not to the call stack, and I would expect that value to be `0`, not `1`. Also, what causes the program to terminate? Your answer also does not explain why `stdin` is *reversed*, although it's clear that it's due to the recursion and whatever causes termination of the recursion. (The first call to write actually executes last)

Comment: 1) `main()` writes to `eax`, but the expression `write(read(0,&_,1) && main())` tells the compiler to pass the result of `read(0,&_,1) && main()` to `write()` as (parameter 1). In other words, the compiler takes care of pushing that value from `eax` to the stack.

Comment: 2) `read()` returns the number of bytes read, which is 1, and since `main()` doesn't return anything, I think `eax` is still left at 1; and 1 (in eax) && 1 (in eax) equals 1.

Comment: 3) the reversion is simply the result of the flow of execution: `read()` -> `main()` -> `read()` -> `main()`, etc; until `read()` reads 0 bytes from `stdin`; then, the `&&` operation results in 0 and the `main()` body terminates without calling another `main()`. Finally, the parent `write()`s, then the grandparent `write()`s, etc... [@OregonTrail]

Comment: Oh, I see it now. The program terminates because of short-circuit execution of the &&. So clever.

Answer (score 1):

It's taking advantage of ANSI C89's implicit declaration of functions. (Search `implicit declaration` here http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt)

<s>This code golfer must have a system with a syscall called `write` that defaults to `stdout`.</s>

<s>This program doesn't work on my system.</s>

**Update**:

The program works for me if I compile it as a 32-bit application, which gave me a hint as to what's going on.

`read` is writing to the location of the first argument to `main`, which is usually `argc`. If `write` is the three argument `write`, then the value at the address of `argc` to the `current` call to main must be passed as the second argument to write, and the value of `1` must be passed as the third argument of `write`, which is the value of `argc`, because no arguments are passed to the program.

It has something to do with abusing the call stack as the arguments to `write`.

Here's the x86 asm, if someone wants to step through and explain this one. I'm currently working on it, but haven't figured it out completely yet.

```x86
main:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], 1
    lea eax, [esp+12]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 0
    call    read
    test    eax, eax
    je  .L2
    call    main
    test    eax, eax
    je  .L2
    mov eax, 1
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    mov eax, 0
.L3:
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax
    call    write
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Good find with regard to the 32-bit constraint. I was wondering why it didn't work on my (64-bit) system, but _did_ work on ideone.com. Now we have a lead to work on, thanks. Let's see where this goes.

Comment: Building on your effort, I've come to write an answer of my own http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636491/765294. Let me know if you find anything suspect about it -- thanks.

Comment: Cheers! I have very little experience actually reading assembly, but I do know what keywords I need to Google for when my rudimentary knowledge of the nuts and bolts leaves me otherwise stumped (oh, and +1). :)

Comment: (Deleted my comment because I thought it was silly) I asked Will if he has any experience with x86 asm prior to asking this question.